# Variable's value that were created within delayed expansion disappears after ending local

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So, I'm creating a login system for a program I'm doing in batch, and I wanted to get a number assigned per user. For that, I've used "for" to get every folder name (==> the user name) and assign it into a value (==> a separate variable, each with a consecutive whole number (1,2,3,4,...)), but to make the values grow "+1" every time the "for" loops, I had to enable delayed extension. After I endlocal, the variables I had previously created don't exist anymore... Is there any way to repair that?

```
:login
for /f %%b in ('dir %users% ^| find "Dir(s)"') do (set dmva=%%b)
set /a mcdm=%dmva%+10
mode con: cols=60 lines=%mcdm%
set value=0
cls
echo.
echo                        -LogIn-
echo.
echo.
echo  All available users:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /D %%A in (%users%*) do (
    set /a value+=1
    set !value!=%%~nA
    echo   !value! -^> %%~nA ^(%%~tA^)
)
::bellow it does print a user's name
echo !1!
endlocal
::but after ending local it doesn't anymore
echo %1%
echo.
echo  Other Options:
echo   [ENTER] Register New User
echo.
set /p usrn=^>^> 
if not defined usrn (goto logon)
set cuser=%usrn%
:sui
del %logged% /f /q
(
    echo %cuser%
) >%logged%
:rui
< %logged% ( 
    set /p cuser=
)
if exist %users%%usrn%\user.id (goto main_menu) else (
    echo  That username isn't registered yet.
    timeout /t 4 >nul
    goto login
)
```

Comment: That's not a bug; it's a feature. `setlocal` creates an instance of local scope and `endlocal` destroys that scope. Traditionally when you need delayed expansion, you'd just have a single `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` once at the top of the script and then the scope exists the entire time. Unless you're processing filenames that contain exclamation points, you really don't need to use `endlocal` at all.

Comment: Upon a very quick view of your code thare are other problems with what you've posted, and which require correction. The most obvious one is that you appear to be defining variables with names consisting of numeric strings. It should be obvious that `%1`, `%2`, `%3` etc. are special argument metavariables, and if you try to use `%1%`, `%2%`, `%3%` etc. the command would parse first the metavariable not the variable you've defined. You need, therefore, to change the way you're naming your variables. Also, you seem to have a label `:login`, and a `goto login`, but you also have a `(goto logon)`!

Comment: Use the `search` facility in the title bar to find `[batch-file]menu` to see past examples and take your choice.

Comment: To pass a (simple) variable value beyond `endlocal`, use `endlocal & set "VAR=%VAR%"`…

Comment: @Compo about the logon one, it's actually another label for the user to register itself (I did rename it after this post). About defining variables with numeric strings, Imma try searching for a solution, the way Magoo suggested. Thanks y'all for helping!!